# Output a binary vector of classes from Sklearn's svm.SVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Is there a way to make my Support Vector Machine classifier output a vector of binary classes?

```
     from sklearn import svm

     X_train = np.array([ [35.0,15.0], [36.0,15.5], [0,0] ]) #train
     y_train = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # classes
     X_new = np.array([[36.2,15.0]])

     clf = svm.SVC()
     clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
     pred = clf.predict(X_new)
     print(pred)
```

Output:

```
array([2])
```

What I want instead is to get a vector of ones and zeroes, with one denoting the predicted class and 0 otherwise:

```
array([0,1,0])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a post-processing:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn import svm


X_train = np.array([ [35.0,15.0], [36.0,15.5], [0,0] ]) #train
y_train = np.array([1, 2, 3])

# postprecessor
hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
hot_encoder.fit(y_train.reshape(-1,1))

# classes
X_new = np.array([[36.2,15.0]])

clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict(X_new)

pred_ = hot_encoder.transform(pred.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
print(pred_)

# results 
# array([0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: This seems to do it. Thanks.
Would please explain what this line achieves: 

pred_ = hot_encoder.transform(pred.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

Comment: Starting from reshape, we make sure that our data input is in correct dimensions. We hot encoded out target with fit. We did not have to fit_transform our target data as we were going to use the encoder as a postprocessor. Using hot_encoder.transform we transform the prediction to the hot encoding, and ask for the array.